# Testing restfull controllers with profiler - Laravel 3

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I am using laravel 3. I enabled the profiler. It's working fine when I am viewing views but when I try to test the Restfull controllers, all of the html of profiler also comes in response. How to get rid of this?

Comment: Can't you just turn off the profiler ?

Comment: We frequently test controllers and view the result on front end. It's not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `done` event where `Laravel` adds the profiler to the final response

```
Event::override('laravel.done', function(){ // return nothing });
```

if you override it before you return the response, then i think it won't attach `profiler` but it may also if you have custom events listening for `done` event then they may not work. Or maybe you can add a `after` filter like

```
Route::filter('after', function ($response) {
    Event::override('laravel.done', function(){ // return nothing });
});
```